# Issue Installing Elastix 4.0 via Bootable USB - CentOS7 Error

Tags: usb, centos7, elastix, bootable

**Goal**

I was attempting to install Elastix 4.0 on a home PC via a Bootable USB, but never had any luck getting it to install past the CentOS7 part (it kept giving me a "Warning: /dev/root does not exist" error).

**What I've Tried**

My main PC is Windows 10 Pro, so after downloading the latest Elastix 4.0 .iso from "http://www.elastix.com/en/downloads/" (Elastix-4.0.74-Stable-x86_64-bin-10Feb2016.iso) I used UNetbootin to create my Bootable USB for Elastix 4.0. I put the now Bootable USB into the PC I want to put Elastix 4.0 on and started it up.

It gave me the "Install Elastix 4" menu, so I hit enter and waited. Then the install proceeded to do its checks for CentOS7, but ended up getting stuck and gave me an error message "dracut-initqueue[580]: Warning: Could not boot." and "Warning: /dev/root does not exist".

This is where I am stuck and cannot proceed.

***EDIT #1***: I signed up for the Elastix forms, and someone else also had this issue. They said they downloaded the .iso and used Rufus to make a Bootable USB, and then booted the installation using the Troubleshooting -> Install CentOS 7 using Basic Graphics ... but according to them, that apparently corrupted something else and then they opted to just use a DVD.

***EDIT #2***: I tested this, and making a Bootable DVD of the .iso does work great for local machines. Installing it via a VM also seems to work without hassle. As a personal goal, I would like to get this working via a Bootable USB.

**Research**

I did some research but a lot of the solutions I've noticed are using the dd command in Linux to make a Bootable USB for just CentOS7 because it is (was?) known that UNetbootin did not properly make a Bootable USB for CentOS7, and I can't seem to find anything that would assist in making the Elastix 4.0 .iso work properly via a Bootable USB. I did try other tools such as Rufus 2.7, Win32 Disk Imager, ISO2USB, and dd for Windows, though most rendered my USB not bootable at all (Rufus worked OK, but still got stuck at the CentOS7 part). Also, installing via a CD/DVD is not ideal, as I have no CD/DVD drive (and I want to see if I can get this working via a Bootable USB drive).

There seem to be a few guides out there for trying to create a Bootable USB for Elastix 2.x, but nothing for Elastix 4.0. Reviewing those, it looks like the guides reference some files that do not exist in the new .iso (ex: ks_default.cfg). Still, my issue pertains mainly to the CentOS7 error I'm getting so I don't think this is related.

Any assistance with this is appreciated, and if you require more information from my end just let me know. I'm willing to try / re-try anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find some valid method? I'm struggle with this issue to months.

Answer (score 0):

http://henrysittechblog.blogspot.ru/2014/01/install-elastix-from-usb-step-by-step.html

Look for this line, but it may change:

> append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 inst.ks=**cdrom**:/dev/**cdrom**:/ks/anaconda-ks.cfg quiet

Change it to:

> append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 inst.ks=**sdb1**:/dev/**sdb1**:/ks/anaconda-ks.cfg quiet

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i solve this problem 80%.

i did some manual change at line:

inst.ks=**cdrom**:/dev/cdrom:/ks/anaconda-ks.cfg quiet

Mine:

inst.ks=**scsi**:/dev/sdb1:/ks/anaconda-ks.cfg quiet

hd is not recogniced by Centos7.

Answer (score -2):

made my usb bootable with rufus 2.9
then open isolinux.cfg with notepad++
just change the line

```
inst.ks=hd:sdb1:/ks/anaconda-ks.cfg quiet
```

where sdb1 used to say cdrom

Comment: Can you add some explanation of why you did this?